# Why does kicad complain about a voltage source not being driven?

Tags: kicad

What does it mean to kicad that a pin is driven?

I have a 12V rail connected to a battery positive terminal in kicad. Kicad says the 12V rail is not driven. Why does it say that? In fact, it tends to shift around depending on whenever I redraw the wire and run a design rules check on it. I'm trying to make sure the board has a battery input, when it is drawn up on PCBnew.

[image: DesignRulesFail]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Electrical Rules Check tries to ensure that everything that is connected to a single net fits together. The quick summary is that a valid net has

- either power (`power_in`, `power_out`) or data (`input`, `bidi`, `output`) pins, not a mixture of them
- at least one pin that can drive the net (`power_out` for power nets, `bidi` or `output` for data nets)
- at most one pin that unconditionally drives the net (`power_out` or `output`)

So a power network needs exactly one `power_out` connected to it.

A known limitation is that connectors' pins are defined as `passive`, because that doesn't immediately lead to a conflict with anything else connected to the same net, so the connector that the power supply is connected to cannot be marked as having a `power_out` pin to placate the ERC.

The `PWR_FLAG` pseudo-component provides a single `power_out` pin, so you can avoid the warning here. The ERC will complain if the same net has two `PWR_FLAG`s, or a `PWR_FLAG` and some other component with a `power_out` pin (such as a linear regulator).

Answer (score 9):

In KiCad the power nets (grounds and sources) should be marked with special symbol "PWR_FLAG" which is located under "power ports" category.

Comment: Does that need to be applied to every net that has a power port on it?

Comment: Yes, unless it's the same net, of course.

Comment: I add power flags but the problem jumps around to other pins. I cant seem to find a way to fix this.

Comment: @user1584421 I don not know how much have changed since 2015 when this answer was written :) But the power flag applies to nets, not pins. If all the pins are connected to the same power net I would be surprised that different pins connected to it will behave differently.