# How to fix ERC error for power pins

Tags: schematics, kicad

I'm working on a board in KiCad that is supplied with 12V regulated power which comes from a terminal block (`1725753`) and then it's routed to a `DRV8871` DC motor driver's supply pin. Now the ERC flags this with "Error: Input Power pin not driven by any Output Power pins" because I'm not able to assign the terminal block that's hooked uup to the +12V rail as output. How do i best resolve that issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does kicad complain about a voltage source not being driven?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/173960/why-does-kicad-complain-about-a-voltage-source-not-being-driven)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to: [Why does kicad complain about a voltage source not being driven?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/173960/why-does-kicad-complain-about-a-voltage-source-not-being-driven?rq=1)

This is KiCad telling you that you have a pin that should be driven by a net that can supply power. An example is an op-amp V_DD pin is expected to be driven by a constant voltage source that can supply a reasonable amount of current. So if you hook up a regulator that have a pin with the "Output Power" type, the op-amp will be happy. If you just have a passive connection, you will get an ERC telling you that the power input is attached to a passive pin, and isn't driven adequately.

Excerpt from my own work:

[image]

See top left for where the PWR_FLAGs are.

[image]